# How to Get the Id variable from the XML in c#?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

Full XML for reference as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>

<feed xml:base="http://pinpoint.microsoft.com/en-US/syndicate/"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"
  xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <title type="text">Partners</title>
  <id>http://google.com/en-US/syndicate/Partners</id>
  <updated>2014-01-20T12:29:25Z</updated>
  <link rel="self" title="Partners" href="Partners" />
  <entry>
    <id>http://google.com/en-US/syndicate/Partners('429')</id>
    <title type="text">Light Systems</title>
    <summary type="text">
      How may we help you? will help you address concerns like security and productivity that may be delaying your transition to a work anywhere, anytime workforce. Mac, Unix and Linux platforms. Whatever your size or need, we have an IT plan that will work for your business.
    </summary>
    <published>2009-07-27T14:23:39-07:00</published>
    <updated>2014-01-10T15:00:41-08:00</updated>
    <author>
      <name>Google Production</name>
      <uri>http://google.com/</uri>
      <email>calamity@google.com</email>
    </author>
    <link rel="edit" title="Partner" href="Partners('429')" />
    <link rel="http://google.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Links" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed"
      title="Links" href="Partners('429')/Links">
      <m:inline>
        <feed>
          <title type="text">Links</title>
          <id>http://google.com/en-US/syndicate/Partners('429')/Links</id>
          <updated>2014-01-20T12:29:25Z</updated>
          <link rel="self" title="Links" href="Partners('429')/Links" />
          <entry>
            <id>http://google.com/en-US/syndicate/Links('partnerpage')</id>
            <title type="text">
            </title>
            <updated>2014-01-20T12:29:25Z</updated>
            <author>
              <name />
            </author>
            <link rel="edit" title="Link" href="Links('partnerpage')" />
            <category term="Google.Commerce.Marketplace.Syndicate.V2010_05.Link"
                scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
            <content type="application/xml">
              <m:properties>
                <d:Type>partnerpage</d:Type>
                <d:Description>Partner Page</d:Description>
                <d:Url>http://google.com/en-US/PartnerDetails.aspx?PartnerId=429&amp;wt.mc_id=ht43</d:Url>
              </m:properties>
            </content>
          </entry>
          <entry>
            <id>http://google.com/en-US/syndicate/Links('partnerproductlist')</id>
            <title type="text">
            </title>
            <updated>2014-01-20T12:29:25Z</updated>
            <author>
              <name />
            </author>
            <link rel="edit" title="Link" href="Links('partnerproductlist')" />
            <category term="Google.Commerce.Marketplace.Syndicate.V2010_05.Link"
                scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
            <content type="application/xml">
              <m:properties>
                <d:Type>partnerproductlist</d:Type>
                <d:Description>Partner Product List</d:Description>
                <d:Url>http://google.com/en-US/PartnerDetails.aspx?partnerId=429&amp;CurrentTab=1&amp;wt.mc_id=ht43</d:Url>
              </m:properties>
            </content>
          </entry>
          <entry>
            <id>http://google.com/en-US/syndicate/Links('partnerreviewpage')</id>
            <title type="text">
            </title>
            <updated>2014-01-20T12:29:25Z</updated>
            <author>
              <name />
            </author>
            <link rel="edit" title="Link" href="Links('partnerreviewpage')" />
            <category term="Google.Commerce.Marketplace.Syndicate.V2010_05.Link"
                scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
            <content type="application/xml">
              <m:properties>
                <d:Type>partnerreviewpage</d:Type>
                <d:Description>Partner Review Page</d:Description>
                <d:Url>http://google.com/en-US/PartnerDetails.aspx?partnerId=429&amp;CurrentTab=2&amp;wt.mc_id=ht43</d:Url>
              </m:properties>
            </content>
          </entry>
          <entry>
            <id>http://google.com/en-US/syndicate/Links('partnerlocationpage')</id>
            <title type="text">
            </title>
            <updated>2014-01-20T12:29:25Z</updated>
            <author>
              <name />
            </author>
            <link rel="edit" title="Link" href="Links('partnerlocationpage')" />
            <category term="Google.Commerce.Marketplace.Syndicate.V2010_05.Link"
                scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
            <content type="application/xml">
              <m:properties>
                <d:Type>partnerlocationpage</d:Type>
                <d:Description>Partner Location Page</d:Description>
                <d:Url>http://google.com/en-US/PartnerDetails.aspx?partnerId=429&amp;CurrentTab=3&amp;wt.mc_id=ht43</d:Url>
              </m:properties>
            </content>
          </entry>
          <entry>
            <id>http://google.com/en-US/syndicate/Links('partnerrfipage')</id>
            <title type="text">
            </title>
            <updated>2014-01-20T12:29:25Z</updated>
            <author>
              <name />
            </author>
            <link rel="edit" title="Link" href="Links('partnerrfipage')" />
            <category term="Google.Commerce.Marketplace.Syndicate.V2010_05.Link"
                scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
            <content type="application/xml">
              <m:properties>
                <d:Type>partnerrfipage</d:Type>
                <d:Description>Partner RFI Page</d:Description>
                <d:Url>http://google.microsoft.com/en-US/RFI.aspx?partnerId=429&amp;wt.mc_id=ht43</d:Url>
              </m:properties>
            </content>
          </entry>
          <entry>
            <id>http://google.com/en-US/syndicate/Links('partnerwebsite')</id>
            <title type="text">
            </title>
            <updated>2014-01-20T12:29:25Z</updated>
            <author>
              <name />
            </author>
            <link rel="edit" title="Link" href="Links('partnerwebsite')" />
            <category term="Google.Commerce.Marketplace.Syndicate.V2010_05.Link"
                scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
            <content type="application/xml">
              <m:properties>
                <d:Type>partnerwebsite</d:Type>
                <d:Description>Website</d:Description>
                <d:Url>http://google.com/en-US/syndicate/relay/partner/website?id=429&amp;link=http%3a%2f%2fwww.systems.com&amp;TrackID=ht43</d:Url>
              </m:properties>
            </content>
          </entry>
          <entry>
            <id>http://google.com/en-US/syndicate/Links('partnerlogo')</id>
            <title type="text">
            </title>
            <updated>2014-01-20T12:29:25Z</updated>
            <author>
              <name />
            </author>
            <link rel="edit" title="Link" href="Links('partnerlogo')" />
            <category term="Microsoft.Commerce.Marketplace.Syndicate.V2010_05.Link"
                scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
            <content type="application/xml">
              <m:properties>
                <d:Type>partnerlogo</d:Type>
                <d:Description>Logo</d:Description>
                <d:Url>http://www.systems.com/lan_logo.jpg</d:Url>
              </m:properties>
            </content>
          </entry>
        </feed>
      </m:inline>
    </link>
    <link rel="http://google.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Locations" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed"
      title="Locations" href="Partners('429')/Locations">
      <m:inline>
        <feed>
          <title type="text">Locations</title>
          <id>http://google.com/en-US/syndicate/Partners('429')/Locations</id>
          <updated>2014-01-20T12:29:25Z</updated>
          <link rel="self" title="Locations" href="Partners('429')/Locations" />
          <entry>
            <id>http://google.com/en-US/syndicate/Locations(1)</id>
            <title type="text">
            </title>
            <updated>2014-01-20T12:29:25Z</updated>
            <author>
              <name />
            </author>
            <link rel="edit" title="Location" href="Locations(1)" />
            <category term="Google.Commerce.Marketplace.Syndicate.V2010_05.Location"
                scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
            <content type="application/xml">
              <m:properties>
                <d:Id m:type="Edm">1</d:Id>
                <d:Address>Crossing Park, Suite E</d:Address>
                <d:City>Norwalk</d:City>
                <d:State>CT</d:State>
                <d:Country>USA</d:Country>
                <d:PostalCode>30071</d:PostalCode>
                <d:HQ m:type="Edm.Boolean">true</d:HQ>
                <d:Latitude m:type="Edm.Double">566</d:Latitude>
                <d:Longitude m:type="Edm.Double">-56.56</d:Longitude>
                <d:ContactName m:null="true" />
                <d:ContactPhoneNumber>+1 9175391100</d:ContactPhoneNumber>
                <d:ContactPhoneExtension m:null="true" />
                <d:ContactFaxNumber>+1 9175391100</d:ContactFaxNumber>
              </m:properties>
            </content>
          </entry>
        </feed>
      </m:inline>
    </link>
    <link rel="http://google.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Products" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed"
      title="Products" href="Partners('429')/Products" />
    <link rel="http://google.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Categories" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed"
      title="Categories" href="Partners('429')/Categories" />
    <category term="google.Marketplace.Syndicate.V2010_05.Partner"
        scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:View>v244</d:View>
        <d:Id>429</d:Id>
        <d:NativeId>630</d:NativeId>
        <d:Name>Systems</d:Name>
        <d:Description xml:space="preserve">will help </d:Description>
        <d:RatingAverage m:type="Edm.Decimal">555</d:RatingAverage>
        <d:RatingCount m:type="Edm.Int32">56</d:RatingCount>
        <d:Certification>Registered Member</d:Certification>
        <d:Search m:null="true" />
        <d:Loc m:null="true" />
        <d:Dist m:null="true" />
        <d:Cat m:null="true" />
      </m:properties>
    </content>
    <rights type="text">Copyright &amp;copy; 2011 Google Corporation</rights>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>http://google.com/en-US/syndicate/Partners('4294')</id>
    <title type="text">Wholesale Intl.</title>
    <summary type="text">SQL Server </summary>
    <published>2009-07-21T14:23:50-07:00</published>
    <updated>2013-08-20T02:17:21-07:00</updated>
    <author>
      <name>google</name>
      <uri>http://google.com/</uri>
      <email>gmail.com</email>
    </author>
    <link rel="edit" title="Partner" href="Partners('4294')" />
    <link rel="http://google.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Links" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed"
      title="Links" href="Partners('4294')/Links">
      <m:inline>
        <feed>
          <title type="text">Links</title>
          <id>http://google.com/en-US/syndicate/Partners('4294')/Links</id>
          <updated>2014-01-20T12:29:25Z</updated>
          <link rel="self" title="Links" href="Partners('4294')/Links" />
          <entry>
            <id>http://google.com/en-US/syndicate/Links('partnerpage')</id>
            <title type="text">
            </title>
            <updated>2014-01-20T12:29:25Z</updated>
            <author>
              <name />
            </author>
            <link rel="edit" title="Link" href="Links('partnerpage')" />
            <category term="Google.Commerce.Marketplace.Syndicate.V2010_05.Link"
                scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
            <content type="application/xml">
              <m:properties>
                <d:Type>partnerpage</d:Type>
                <d:Description>Page</d:Description>
                <d:Url>http://google.microsoft.com/en-US/PartnerDetails.aspx?PartnerId=4294&amp;wt.mc_id=ht43</d:Url>
              </m:properties>
            </content>
          </entry>
          <entry>
            <id>http://google.com/en-US/syndicate/Links('partnerproductlist')</id>
            <title type="text">
            </title>
            <updated>2014-01-20T12:29:25Z</updated>
            <author>
              <name />
            </author>
            <link rel="edit" title="Link" href="Links('partnerproductlist')" />
            <category term="Google.Commerce.Marketplace.Syndicate.V2010_05.Link"
                scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
            <content type="application/xml">
              <m:properties>
                <d:Type>partnerproductlist</d:Type>
                <d:Description>Product List</d:Description>
                <d:Url>http://google.com/en-US/PartnerDetails.aspx?partnerId=4294&amp;CurrentTab=1&amp;wt.mc_id=ht43</d:Url>
              </m:properties>
            </content>
          </entry>
          <entry>
            <id>http://google.com/en-US/syndicate/Links('partnerreviewpage')</id>
            <title type="text">
            </title>
            <updated>2014-01-20T12:29:25Z</updated>
            <author>
              <name />
            </author>
            <link rel="edit" title="Link" href="Links('pinpointpartnerreviewpage')" />
            <category term="Google.Marketplace.Syndicate.V2010_05.Link"
                scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
            <content type="application/xml">
              <m:properties>
                <d:Type>partnerreviewpage</d:Type>
                <d:Description>Review Page</d:Description>
                <d:Url>http://google.com/en-US/PartnerDetails.aspx?partnerId=4294&amp;CurrentTab=2&amp;wt.mc_id=ht43</d:Url>
              </m:properties>
            </content>
          </entry>
          <entry>
            <id>http://google.com/en-US/syndicate/Links('partnerlocationpage')</id>
            <title type="text">
            </title>
            <updated>2014-01-20T12:29:25Z</updated>
            <author>
              <name />
            </author>
            <link rel="edit" title="Link" href="Links('partnerlocationpage')" />
            <category term="google.Marketplace.Syndicate.V2010_05.Link"
                scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
            <content type="application/xml">
              <m:properties>
                <d:Type>partnerlocationpage</d:Type>
                <d:Description>Location Page</d:Description>
                <d:Url>http://google.com/en-US/PartnerDetails.aspx?partnerId=4294&amp;CurrentTab=3&amp;wt.mc_id=ht43</d:Url>
              </m:properties>
            </content>
          </entry>
          <entry>
            <id>http://google.com/en-US/syndicate/Links('partnerrfipage')</id>
            <title type="text">
            </title>
            <updated>2014-01-20T12:29:25Z</updated>
            <author>
              <name />
            </author>
            <link rel="edit" title="Link" href="Links('partnerrfipage')" />
            <category term="Google.Marketplace.Syndicate.V2010_05.Link"
                scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
            <content type="application/xml">
              <m:properties>
                <d:Type>partnerrfipage</d:Type>
                <d:Description>RFI Page</d:Description>
                <d:Url>http://pinpoint.microsoft.com/en-US/RFI.aspx?partnerId=4294&amp;wt.mc_id=ht43</d:Url>
              </m:properties>
            </content>
          </entry>
          <entry>
            <id>http://google.com/en-US/syndicate/Links('partnerwebsite')</id>
            <title type="text">
            </title>
            <updated>2014-01-20T12:29:25Z</updated>
            <author>
              <name />
            </author>
            <link rel="edit" title="Link" href="Links('partnerwebsite')" />
            <category term="google.Marketplace.Syndicate.V2010_05.Link"
                scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
            <content type="application/xml">
              <m:properties>
                <d:Type>partnerwebsite</d:Type>
                <d:Description>Website</d:Description>
                <d:Url>http://google.com/en-US/syndicate/relay/partner/website?id=4294&amp;link=http%3a%2f%2fwww.software-intl.com&amp;TrackID=ht43</d:Url>
              </m:properties>
            </content>
          </entry>
          <entry>
            <id>http://google.com/en-US/syndicate/Links('partnerlogo')</id>
            <title type="text">
            </title>
            <updated>2014-01-20T12:29:25Z</updated>
            <author>
              <name />
            </author>
            <link rel="edit" title="Link" href="Links('partnerlogo')" />
            <category term="Google.Commerce.Marketplace.Syndicate.V2010_05.Link"
                scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
            <content type="application/xml">
              <m:properties>
                <d:Type>partnerlogo</d:Type>
                <d:Description>Logo</d:Description>
                <d:Url>http://www.software-intl.com/uploads/2012/04/swi-logo-web.png</d:Url>
              </m:properties>
            </content>
          </entry>
        </feed>
      </m:inline>
    </link>
    <link rel="http://google.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Locations" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed"
      title="Locations" href="Partners('4294')/Locations">
      <m:inline>
        <feed>
          <title type="text">Locations</title>
          <id>http://google.com/en-US/syndicate/Partners('4294')/Locations</id>
          <updated>2014-01-20T12:29:25Z</updated>
          <link rel="self" title="Locations" href="Partners('4294')/Locations" />
          <entry>
            <id>http://google.com/en-US/syndicate/Locations(1)</id>
            <title type="text">
            </title>
            <updated>2014-01-20T12:29:25Z</updated>
            <author>
              <name />
            </author>
            <link rel="edit" title="Location" href="Locations(1)" />
            <category term="Google.Marketplace.Syndicate.V2010_05.Location"
                scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
            <content type="application/xml">
              <m:properties>
                <d:Id m:type="Edm">1</d:Id>
                <d:Address>1114</d:Address>
                <d:City>Longt</d:City>
                <d:State>CT</d:State>
                <d:Country>USA</d:Country>
                <d:PostalCode>80455</d:PostalCode>
                <d:HQ m:type="Edm.Boolean">true</d:HQ>
                <d:Latitude m:type="Edm.Double">4455</d:Latitude>
                <d:Longitude m:type="Edm.Double">444</d:Longitude>
                <d:ContactName>xxxx</d:ContactName>
                <d:ContactPhoneNumber>+1 917000000</d:ContactPhoneNumber>
                <d:ContactPhoneExtension m:null="true" />
                <d:ContactFaxNumber>+1 917000000</d:ContactFaxNumber>
              </m:properties>
            </content>
          </entry>
          <entry>
            <id>http://google.com/en-US/syndicate/Locations(2)</id>
            <title type="text">
            </title>
            <updated>2014-01-20T12:29:25Z</updated>
            <author>
              <name />
            </author>
            <link rel="edit" title="Location" href="Locations(2)" />
            <category term="google.Marketplace.Syndicate.V2010_05.Location"
                scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
            <content type="application/xml">
              <m:properties>
                <d:Id m:type="Edm">2</d:Id>
                <d:Address>Suite 206</d:Address>
                <d:City>Moo</d:City>
                <d:State>CT</d:State>
                <d:Country>USA</d:Country>
                <d:PostalCode>88154</d:PostalCode>
                <d:HQ m:type="Edm.Boolean">false</d:HQ>
                <d:Latitude m:type="Edm.Double">32.01</d:Latitude>
                <d:Longitude m:type="Edm.Double">-333</d:Longitude>
                <d:ContactName>cddc</d:ContactName>
                <d:ContactPhoneNumber>1-917000000</d:ContactPhoneNumber>
                <d:ContactPhoneExtension>457</d:ContactPhoneExtension>
                <d:ContactFaxNumber>917000000</d:ContactFaxNumber>
              </m:properties>
            </content>
          </entry>
        </feed>
      </m:inline>
    </link>
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Products"
      type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="Products" href="Partners('4294')/Products" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Categories"
      type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="Categories" href="Partners('4294')/Categories" />
    <category term="Google.Commerce.Marketplace.Syndicate.V2010_05.Partner"
        scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:View>v45</d:View>
        <d:Id>4294</d:Id>
        <d:NativeId>7104</d:NativeId>
        <d:Name>Wholesale Intl.</d:Name>
        <d:Description> license or a comprehensive company-wide license agreement we can assist you to license your Microsoft software. </d:Description>
        <d:RatingAverage m:type="Edm.Decimal">455</d:RatingAverage>
        <d:RatingCount m:type="Edm.Int32">55</d:RatingCount>
        <d:Certification>hagh</d:Certification>
        <d:Search m:null="true" />
        <d:Loc m:null="true" />
        <d:Dist m:null="true" />
        <d:Cat m:null="true" />
      </m:properties>
    </content>
    <rights type="text">Copyright &amp;copy; 2011 Google Corporation</rights>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

The code being used to generate the information is

```
using( var w1 = new StreamWriter(path1,true))
{
  // Read and parse the required information from 'direct.xml'
  var reader1 = new StreamReader("C:/Users/Administrator/Downloads/direct.xml");
  var xmlDoc1 = XDocument.Load(reader1);
  XNamespace atom = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";
  XNamespace metadata = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata";
  XNamespace dataservices = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices";

  var result = xmlDoc1.Root.Elements(atom + "entry")
    .Select(e => new
    {
      Title = (string)e.Element(atom + "title"),
      Id = (string)e.Element(atom + "id"),
      // Urls = e.Elements(atom + "link")
        //  .Where(l => l.Element(metadata + "inline") != null)
          //.SelectMany(l => l.Element(metadata + "inline")
        //  .Element(atom + "feed")
          //.Elements(atom + "entry")
          //.Select(e1 => (string)e1.Element(atom + "content")
        //  .Element(metadata + "properties")
          //.Element(dataservices + "Url")).Where(k => k != null)),
      City = e.Elements(atom + "link")
        .Where(l => l.Element(metadata + "inline") != null)
        .SelectMany(l => l.Element(metadata + "inline")
        .Element(atom + "feed")
        .Elements(atom + "entry")
        .Select(e1 => (string)e1.Element(atom + "content")
          .Element(metadata + "properties")
          .Element(dataservices + "City"))
        .Where(u => u != null)),
      State = e.Elements(atom + "link")
        .Where(l => l.Element(metadata + "inline") != null)
        .SelectMany(l => l.Element(metadata + "inline")
        .Element(atom + "feed")
        .Elements(atom + "entry")
        .Select(e1 => (string)e1.Element(atom + "content")
          .Element(metadata + "properties")
          .Element(dataservices + "State"))
        .Where(u => u != null)),
      Country = e.Elements(atom + "link")
        .Where(l => l.Element(metadata + "inline") != null)
        .SelectMany(l => l.Element(metadata + "inline")
          .Element(atom + "feed")
          .Elements(atom + "entry")
          .Select(e1 => (string)e1.Element(atom + "content")
          .Element(metadata + "properties")
          .Element(dataservices + "Country"))
        .Where(u => u != null)),
      Identity = e.Element(atom +"content")
        .Element(metadata + "properties")
        .Element(dataservices + "Id")
    });

  foreach (var entry in result)
  {
    foreach (var sta in entry.State)
    {
      foreach (var ci in entry.City)
      {
        foreach (var coun in entry.Country)
        {
          // Debug.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2},{3}", entry.Title, entry.Id, ci);
          String uniqueId = BusinessNeedNumber + IndustryFocusNumber + Competency + sta + ci + coun+entry.Identity;
          Debug.WriteLine(uniqueId);

          // just getting the Id value by replacement 
          // Writing onto CSV file
          String advertisername = entry.Title.Replace(",", "&");
          var data = string.Format(advertisername + "," + BusinessNeedNumber + "," + IndustryFocusNumber
                                       + "," + Competency + "," + URL + "," + signature + "," + SignatureURL + "," + sta + "," + ci + "," + coun + "," + uniqueId + "," + entry.Identity );
          w1.WriteLine(data, true);
          w1.Flush();


        }
      }
    }
  }
  w1.Close();
  reader1.Close();
  return;
```

I want to parse the id field to receive the Id information which is under

```
entry,content,properties,id
```

Desired output is

```
 4294
```

which is here

```
<d:Id>4294</d:Id>
```

But I am getting the output as

```
 <d:Id xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices">4294</d:Id>
```

Do not understand why am I getting that particular information and not just the 'Id' value

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use entry.Identity.Value instead of entry.Identity:

```
String uniqueId = BusinessNeedNumber + IndustryFocusNumber + Competency + sta + ci + coun+entry.Identity.Value;
```